# CakePHP Find with HABTM using only the Join Table

Tags: cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a Goal model that HasAndBelongsToMany Users. This HABTM is named Participant. When I try to find all the Participants of a goal, the join table for this HABTM is not being used. Here is the related code in the goal model.

```
class Goal extends AppModel {
    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Participant' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'joinTable' => 'goal_participants',
        'foreignKey' => 'goal_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'user_id',
        'unique' => true,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'deleteQuery' => '',
        'insertQuery' => ''
    ));

    function getParticipantIDs($goalID) {
        $this->bindModel(array('hasOne' => array('Participant')));
        return $this->find('list', array(
            'fields' => array('Participant.user_id'),
            'conditions' => array('Participant.goal_id' => $goalID)
        ));
    }
}
```

I am binding the Participant as hasOne so that it will create a join in the query, but I get the following error:

```
Warning (512): SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'Participant.user_id' in 'field list' [CORE\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo_source.php, line 525]
Query: SELECT `Participant`.`id`, `Participant`.`user_id` FROM `users` AS `Participant`   WHERE `Participant`.`goal_id` = '19' AND `Participant`.`status` != 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I edited the answer after OP's comment.*

If i understand well what you intend to do, this piece of code might help :

```
function getParticipantIDs($goalID) {
    $participants = $this->GoalParticipant->find('list', array(
        'fields' => array('user_id'),
        'conditions' => array('goal_id' => $goalID)
    ));
    return array_values($participants);
}
```

I'm not 100% sure GoalParticipant is the correct syntax. I'm pretty sure that if the join table was named goals_participants, the correct syntax would be GoalsParticipant but as it's named goal_participants I guess it might be GoalParticipant.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, G.J. Unfortunately it isn't working, and I have a feeling I didn't explain my schema. Goals contains and `id` field, as does Participant (aka Users). The table that joins them is called `goal_participants`, which has the fields `goal_id` and `user_id`. What I am looking for is the rows in the `goal_participants` table with the specified `$goalID`. The query you gave is looking for `goal_id` in the Users table (when it is really in the `goal_participants` table). Any idea how to grab the data from the join table instead?

Comment: my bad. I have edited my answer. I think it should be correct now